# How to add new method / property to imported library module in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am new to TypeScript and I want to know the correct way to add new method/property to an imported library module.

I use the external library Telegraf (https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf) to build a bot.

Here is my code:

```
const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
bot.context.db = {
  getUser: (data: any) => {
    User.findByTelegramIdOrCreate(data);
  },
};
bot.on('text', (ctx) => {
  const user = ctx.db.getUser(ctx.message.from);
  ctx.reply(`Hello, ${user.username}`);
});
bot.launch();
```

After launch I get the next errors:

```
src/index.ts:10:13 - error TS2339: Property 'db' does not exist on type 'TelegrafContext'
src/index.ts:16:20 - error TS2339: Property 'db' does not exist on type 'TelegrafContext'.
```

The library provides the next typing:

```
export declare class Telegraf<
  TContext extends TelegrafContext
> extends Composer<TContext> {
  /**
   * Use this property to get/set bot token
   */
  token: string

  /**
   * Use this property to control reply via webhook feature.
   */
  webhookReply: boolean

  /**
   * Use this property to get telegram instance
   */
  telegram: Telegram

  /**
   * Use this property to extend context and support your custom interface
   */
  context: TContext

  /**
   * Telegraf options
   */
  options: TOptions

  ...
```

How can I update type TelegrafContext with `db` property?

Comment: See this [github issue](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/issues/606) for a solution. Feel free to self-answer if it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just extend the class...

```
class TelegrafDB extends Telegraf {
    /*treat this just like a normal class, you can add your db property along with 
    any other properties or methods you want*/
}
```

then change your code to be `const bot = new TelegrafDB(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)`